How to track long-term events (one year) in Firebase Analytics with cordova-plugin-firebasex in Ionic 4?
Question
I'm working on an Ionic 4 app where I'm using the cordova-plugin-firebasex plugin to track specific events. My goal is to generate a long-term report (e.g., over a one-year period) for an event called measurement_added. This event has a parameter measure_name, which can take on values such as weight, step_count, or glucose.
Code Example
Here is the code I’m currently using to log events:
this.firebaseX.logEvent('measurement_added', {
  measure_name: correspondingMeasure.name,
  timestamp: new Date().toISOString()
});


What I've Tried
Currently, I can only view data for a short period (30 minutes), but I am unable to access or generate reports for longer durations, such as one year.
Goal
I want to be able to track measurement_added events with different measure_name values over extended periods.

Ideally, I’d like guidance on how to generate a report that filters by measure_name and covers a full year.

My Question
What steps should I follow to:
Set up Firebase Analytics to store and access long-term data (one year)?
Generate a comprehensive report using this data?
Access or export this data over longer timeframes, like one year, rather than just 30 minutes?

I'm using Ionic 4 with the cordova-plugin-firebasex plugin.
Any guidance or best practices on handling long-term data tracking and generating reports in Firebase Analytics with this setup would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.
